# Managing dates in SPSS - Time difference in months

Tags: date, spss

Im a novice SPSS user and are working on a data set with two columns, customer ID and order date. I want to create a third variable with a month integer of number of inactive months since the observed customer ID:s last order date. This is how the data looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will create some sample data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/ID (f3) OrderDate (adate10).
begin data
1 09/18/2016
1 03/02/2017
1 05/12/2017
2 06/06/2016
2 09/09/2017
end data.
```

Now you can run the following syntax to create a variable that contains the number of complete months between the date in the present row and the date in the previous row:

```
sort cases by ID OrderDate.
if ID=lag(ID) MonthSince=DATEDIF(OrderDate, lag(OrderDate), "months").
```